# illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions

Tags: java, hibernate, session, transactions

how fix this error and what best way to use sessions in hibernate are one session and multi transactions in all application or what i do is good please check next code

and i hope you give me answer with correct code and how make it in one session if it best way

this is error

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions
at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.setSession(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:112)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.reassociateProxy(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:595)
at org.hibernate.engine.internal.StatefulPersistenceContext.unproxyAndReassociate(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:642)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:90)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultDeleteEventListener.onDelete(DefaultDeleteEventListener.java:74)
```

the hibernate transactions and implements

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();

Query query = null;
Transaction transaction = null;

@Override
public void delete(Car o) {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(o);
    transaction.commit();

}

@Override
public List<Car> findAll() {
    List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    try {
        query = session.createQuery("from Car");
        carsList = query.list();
        for (Iterator iterator = carsList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            Car car = (Car) iterator.next();
        }
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return carsList;
}

@Override
public Car findById(int id) {
    query = session.createQuery("from Car where id=:id");
    query.setParameter("id", id);
    Car car = (Car) query.list().get(0);
    return car;
}

@Override
public void insert(Car o) {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(o);
    transaction.commit();
}

@Override
public void update(Car o) {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(o);
    transaction.commit();
}

@Override
public List<Car> findByCarLicense(CarLicense carLicense) {
    List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    try {
        query = session.createQuery("from Car where carLicense=:carLicense");
        query.setParameter("carLicense", carLicense);
        carsList = query.list();
        for (Iterator iterator = carsList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            Car car = (Car) iterator.next();
        }
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return carsList;
}

@Override
public List<Car> findByPruCompany(PruCompany pruCompany) {
    List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    try {
        query = session.createQuery("from Car where pruCompany=:pruCompany");
        query.setParameter("pruCompany", pruCompany);
        carsList = query.list();
        for (Iterator iterator = carsList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            Car car = (Car) iterator.next();
        }
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return carsList;
}

@Override
public List<Car> findByTypy(String type) {
    List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    try {
        query = session.createQuery("from Car where type=:type");
        query.setParameter("type", type);
        carsList = query.list();
        for (Iterator iterator = carsList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            Car car = (Car) iterator.next();
        }
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return carsList;
}

@Override
public List<Car> findByModel(String model) {
    List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    try {
        query = session.createQuery("from Car where model=:model");
        query.setParameter("model", model);
        carsList = query.list();
        for (Iterator iterator = carsList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            Car car = (Car) iterator.next();
        }
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return carsList;
}

@Override
public List<Car> findByColor(String color) {
    List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    try {
        query = session.createQuery("from Car where color=:color");
        query.setParameter("color", color);
        carsList = query.list();
        for (Iterator iterator = carsList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            Car car = (Car) iterator.next();
        }
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return carsList;
}

@Override
public List<Car> findByNumber(String number) {
    List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    try {
        query = session.createQuery("from Car where number=:number");
        query.setParameter("number", number);
        carsList = query.list();
        for (Iterator iterator = carsList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            Car car = (Car) iterator.next();
        }
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return carsList;
}

@Override
public List<Car> findByKilos(Double kilos) {
    List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    try {
        query = session.createQuery("from Car where kilos=:kilos");
        query.setParameter("kilos", kilos);
        carsList = query.list();
        for (Iterator iterator = carsList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            Car car = (Car) iterator.next();
        }
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return carsList;
}

@Override
public List<Car> findByAvalibity(String avalibity) {
    List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    try {
        query = session.createQuery("from Car where avalibity=:avalibity");
        query.setParameter("avalibity", avalibity);
        carsList = query.list();
        for (Iterator iterator = carsList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            Car car = (Car) iterator.next();
        }
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return carsList;
}

@Override
public Car findByChassisNumber(String chassisNumber) {
    query = session.createQuery("from Car where chassisNumber=:chassisNumber");
    query.setParameter("chassisNumber", chassisNumber);
    Car car = (Car) query.list().get(0);
    return car;
}
```

and HibernateUtil

```
private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
    try {
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(
                "/com/core/util/hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
        return sessionFactory;
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}
public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
public static void shutdown() {
    getSessionFactory().close();
}
```

Comment: Mostly everytime you do a `transaction.commit` you should close your session...

Comment: are this right use  `transaction.commit` and are my way is right

Comment: i try close session still have error

Comment: another thing, is offtopic, what are you trying to do in all your `for()`? For what I see, you are doing nothing, why don't you remove them?

Comment: if i remove 'for()' how get object and please can you write this class by best way to learn thanks

Comment: you get your objects when you call `query.list()`

Comment: please can you write this class by best way and optimize it to learn i'm fresh in hibernate and thank you so so mush

Comment: In my case I had reassigned/filled a lazy-loaded field on an entity (loaded from txn-1) within another (txn-2); and when saving that 'composite' entity in another (txn-3), got this error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not to open your `session` object for all your transactions, instead, open it and close it after everytime you use it, a minimal example taken from what you wrote:

```
public void delete(Car o) {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(o);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

and

```
public List<Car> findAll() {
    List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
    try {
        query = session.createQuery("from Car");
        carsList = query.list();
        for (Iterator iterator = carsList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {
            Car car = (Car) iterator.next();
        }
    } catch (HibernateException he) {
        he.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

    }
    return carsList;
}
```

Could be something like this:

```
public class Transactor {

    public static void delete(Car o) {
        Session session;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        }
        Transaction transaction = null;

        try {
            transaction = session.beginTransaction();
            session.delete(o);
            transaction.commit();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            System.out.println("Error deleting car: " + ex);
            if(transaction != null) {
                transaction.rollback();
            }
        } finally {
            if (session.isOpen()){
                session.close();
            }
        }
    }


    public static List<Car> findAll() {
        Session session;
        try {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
        } catch (HibernateException ex) {
            session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        }
        List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            carsList = session.createQuery("from Car").list();
        } catch (HibernateException he) {
            System.out.println("Error getting cars: " + he);
            he.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (session.isOpen()){
                session.close();
            }
        }
        return carsList;
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is the best way, but is more secure.

**EDIT**

I have edited the example, if you want to try it, you could do something like this:

```
List<Car> carList = Transactor.findAll(); // get all cars
Transactor.delete(myCar);                 // delete an specific car
```

From here, you should be able to complete your class.

Comment: ok , but exception happen   when call delete method  `DAOFactory.getInstance().getCarLicenseDAOImpl().delete(   CRSevice.getInstance().getCarLicenseSrv().getCarLicense());`

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` and 
 
please can you write this class by best way and optimize it to learn i'm fresh in hibernate and thank you so so mush

Comment: I have edit it, I can't do all your class but maybe that could help you.

Comment: ok can just do three method `public List<Car> findAll()` and `public Car findById(int id) ` and `public List<Car> findByCarLicense(CarLicense carLicense)` please , and what about exception

Comment: after update my classes i have exception ` could not initialize proxy - no Session`

Comment: when call this method ` @Override
    public List<Car> findAll() {
     session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        List<Car> carsList = new ArrayList<Car>();
        try {
            carsList = session.createQuery("from Car").list();
            } catch (HibernateException he) {
            he.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
         if(session.isOpen()){
          session.close();
         }
        }
        return carsList;
    }` i want one session to all application in my application i set temp data to use it later

Answer (score 0):

```
Add **@Transactional** annotation to serviceImpl as well as Repository classes
Ex:

**Repository Implementation class:**

@Transactional
@Repository
public class UserRepositoryImpl implements UserRepository {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    
    private Session getSession() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        if(session == null || !session.isOpen()) {
            session = this.sessionFactory.withOptions().openSession();
        }

        return session;
    }

    @Override
    public UserDO getUserById(int id) {
        Session session = getSession();     
        UserDO obj = (UserDO) session.load(UserDO.class, new Integer(id));
        return obj;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateUser(UserDO obj) {
        Session session = getSession();
        session.update(obj);
    }
}

**Service Implementation class:**

@Transactional
@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepo;

    @Override
    public void updateUserDetails() {
    
        UserDO userDO = userRepo.getUserById(user.getUserId());

        userDO.setLastLoginTime(new Date());
    
        userRepo.updateUser(userDO);
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).